# Changing parameters for Pushwoosh in iOS or Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, push-notification, pushwoosh

I am trying to alter the PushNotificationManager.h to change some settings, like I don't want pushes to be received when app is in foreground.

Here is what I have tries:

```
- (void) registerForPushNotifications;
[PushNotificationsManager sharedManager].showPushnotificationAlert = NO;
```

This creates this alert:

```
*Expected identifier or ”(“*
```

Then I tried this:

```
- (void) registerForPushNotifications(){
    [PushNotificationsManager sharedManager].showPushnotificationAlert = NO;
}
```

This creates this alert:

```
*Expected ";" after method prototype*
```

Then this:

```
- (void) registerForPushNotifications([PushNotificationsManager sharedManager].showPushnotificationAlert = NO);
```

Also this throws the same error. What am I doing wrong.

Hoping for help in this matter. I am novice in the XCode part. I build everything from the Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are referring to this file:
https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-sdk-samples/blob/master/Unity/iOS/Plugins/iOS/UnityRuntime.m

This is how you should modify the file:

```
void registerForRemoteNotifications() {
    [PushNotificationManager pushManager].showPushnotificationAlert = NO;
    [[PushNotificationManager pushManager] registerForPushNotifications];
}
```

Do not change `PushNotificationManager.h` file!
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon at the end needs to go (it's the method implementation, not its @interface declaration where the semicolon would be necessary):

```
- (void) registerForPushNotifications;
```

So it becomes this:

```
- (void) registerForPushNotifications {
    [PushNotificationsManager sharedManager].showPushnotificationAlert = NO;
}
```

Needless to say, this isn't legal Objective-C either, it's a mash of Objective-C and C syntax:

```
- (void) registerForPushNotifications(){
```

Comment: This also gives the error: Expected ";" after method prototype. It wants the ; right after registerForPushNotifications? Any idea?

Comment: Just seen this in your question, you attempt to write the method in the .h file but it needs to be in the @implementation of the .m file.